# exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);

Tags: javascript, css-loader, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js app.

I have this configuration (nuxt.config.js):

```
module.exports={
    loading: { color: 'cyan' },
    router: {
    middleware: 'i18n'
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/i18n.js'],
    generate: {
    routes: ['/', '/fr']
    },
    build: {
    vendor: ['axios'],
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
        if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ['css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I launch the server: npm run dev and I get this error message:

```
(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // imports
  3 |
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What version of nuxt? And show your full config file with imports\require

Comment: I use Nuxt version 2.0.0. My `nuxt.config.js` file contains only what I shared here

Comment: create a reproduction on codesandbox